# I want to change the home page menu depending on the login user. How do i do it in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I am able to log-in using Spring-MVC.
Now i would like to change the menu's depending upon the user who logged in.
How do i pass login-username to my home page using spring MVC Controller?
So that i could use that UserName and change the menu according to Login-name?
Is there any framework available for same?
What if i want to send a collection of objects (Which will contain the actions assigned to the login user ) to my home page after successful login?

Is there any better way to do it?

any suggestions would be more appreciated. Need a Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this based on roles then spring security provides jsp taglib to handle this.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Example

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: This would be some relief. Will surely search for it and come back with some questions.

Comment: The above approach would be good if i want to give authorization for for some pages. How about authorizing like 100 jsps? Cant i make it from some application context file or properties files?

Comment: I didn't know that its so huge. You can surely do configuration where you map roles to the menus in properties file, xml file or even database. Based on this configuration you would know for a role what menus you can show.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bhushan's answer, you can also use your custom UserDetails class to store information pertaining to the authenticated user, and pass values to the model from your controller class with `model.put("myParamName", myParam);`

Then, in the JSP, with or without the `authorize` tag, you can refer to model attributes with `${myParam}`. Note that this is not limited to pure HTML content; you may pass Javascript in this fashion as well -- just be wary of the fact that while what is passed may be whatever data type you like (that JSP can handle, anyway), it will be treated as a String when ultimately rendered, so you'll have to escape characters and include line breaks and/or tabs for lengthy content and proper formatting. For example:

**MyController.java**

```
. . .

String myJavascript = "<script>\n\tvar myVar = \"Hello Dheeraj!\";\n\talert(myVar);\n</script";
model.put("someJavascript", myJavascript);

. . .
```

**myPage.jsp**

```
${someJavascript}
```

Now, when that page is called, the client will see the following:

```
. . .

<script>
    var myVar = "Hello Dheeraj!";
    alert(myVar);
</script>
```

You can of course also pass arrays, etc., and loop through items to build `<select>` elements, etc. The user-specific logic will presumably reside on (or be called from) your controller class.

Comment: Can you share some link where i can find how do i send java script to my jsp from controller? Can i send JSON collection included in my java script with ajax , to controller just like the one you shown in  example? So I can show some data in my jsp page from the json collection which i sent from controller?

Comment: [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) is a very basic example of putting information to the model and retrieving it. I use 'model.put("keyName", object), whereas this example uses 'model.addObject("keyName", object)', and there is also 'model.addAttribute("keyName", object)'; I am not sure how these all differ (I expect 'addAttribute' is based off of the '@ModelAttribute' annotation, but I'm unsure).

You can pass Javascript as though it is a string (as in my example).

Comment: sure will give try and come back with some questions.

Comment: Suppose we put some value in key and pain just like above example :- model.put("someJavascript", myJavascript);  Can i retrive it in java script? instead of in JSP?

Comment: Yes and no. The JSP will receive the POJO sent to the model. This will be rendered as plain text as appropriate (based on your JSP logic, etc.). If that plain text includes Javascript (inside `<script>` tags), it will be handled as Javascript. You'll want to experiment with this if it's confusing.

Just remember the order in which things are processed, and remember what is being be received at each stage. If what you ultimately pass to the client (HTML/Javascript) includes formatted Javascript, you'll be able to treat it as you would any other Javascript content on a static page.